# Using Spark to call out-of-process dll functions

Tags: c++, scala, grid, apache-spark, zeromq

We're evaluating wether to use Spark to run our grid calculations and we're having some trouble with a particular use case. Wondering if the community has any good ideas.

We have an extensive library of C++ functions in a dll that we need to use all over the grid. The C++ code base is large, not particularly stable (it falls over frequently) and holds state (thread un-safe). For this reason the dll needs to live out of process.

To handle this we've built a thin zero mq wrapper around the dll and a thin scala zero mq client to handle requests to the dll. We can distribute the zeromq wrapped dll to all the nodes in the grid.

My question is: Is it possible to use Spark to handle this situation? How can I make calls to the zeromq scala client inside an `RDD.map()` call? How can this get handled on the grid? Do we need to serialise the zeromq client?

Any ideas much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to run an instance of your custom server on each node. Then you can create a new client per partition. Instead of `RDD.map` you would use `RDD.mapPartitions`, something like this:

```
rdd.mapPartitions { it =>
  val client = new MyClient("localhost:2345")
  it.map(x => client.calculate(x))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `RDD.pipe` with a line-oriented wrapper might meet your needs.  Your question didn't make entirely clear what the constraints are, especially with respect to the state in the library.